# Javascript timer bug in Opera

Tags: javascript, opera

this is a simple puzzle game using html 5 drag and drop to move spans to their correct spot. A timer starts on the first drag (function drag(e)), and stops when there are no more spans left in the reserve (not shown).

(side question : is there a standard way of beautifying the (m)m : ss timer output I want, or do I have to go on as I am?)

Why does the timer() function work perfectly in chrome and firefox, and yet the seconds reset in Opera at 8 seconds? If I don't try to beautify the seconds and use the commented out line instead, it works perfectly.

Best regards!

```
var timerOn = false;

function drag(e) {
  if (timerOn == false) {
    timerOn = window.setInterval(function(){ timer() }, 1000);
  }
...
}

function timer() {
  var content = document.getElementById("timer").textContent.split(":");
  if (parseInt(content[1]) == 59) {
    content[0] = (parseInt(content[0]) + 1).toString();
    content[1] = "00";
  }
  else {
    var s = parseInt(content[1]) + 1;
    content[1] = (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s.toString();
    //~ content[1] =  s.toString();
  }
  document.getElementById("timer").textContent = content[0] + ":" + content[1];
}

....

<span id="timer">0:00</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some browsers extend JavaScript's `parseInt` to treat the prefix `0` to mean "octal", and `08` is an invalid octal number.

In the various places you use `parseInt`, give it its second argument (the *radix* — e.g., number base — to use), e.g. `parseInt(str, 10)`. (This is a good idea generally, for this very reason.)

I'm surprised that you're still finding this behavior in an up-to-date browser, though, as the ECMAScript5 specification released three and a half years ago explicitly forbids extending `parseInt` in that way, as noted in [Annex E - *Additions and Changes in the 5th Edition that Introduce Incompatibilities with the 3rd Edition*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-E):

> [15.1.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2): The specification of the function `parseInt` no longer allows implementations to treat Strings beginning with a `0` character as octal values.

...and I don't think [§B.1.1 - *Additional Syntax - Numeric Literals*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1) applies to `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot, I would never have found that!

Comment: Originally, nobody intended on following ES5 for non-strict code. It was only mid-2012 that other browsers started moving (Safari 6 (July 2012), IE 10 (standards-mode only; August 2012), Chrome 23 (November 2012), Firefox 21 (May 2013)), thus it all happened a bit too late for the last Presto releases.

Comment: @gsnedders: That seems...surprising...given that ES5 was the result of a *huge* amount of negotiation between the committee and the various implementers. Do you have a reference/citation for that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can't find any single reference, but there's various people on es-discuss essentially stating they cannot see it changing. Try searching es-discuss for "octal" and you'll find a fair few things (several in threads I started, heh!), ranging from MS people saying they don't see them being able to change it, statements about there being no plan to change it in SpiderMonkey, etc. It's somewhat notable that Carakan, whose development quite neatly coincided with the final year or two of ES5, supported the `0`-prefixed `parseInt` as octal.

Comment: Also, Opera 12.1x isn't really up-to-date, it was released in November 2012. In the days of six-week release-cycles, that's *really* old.